# List of all properties in dbpedia that appears in a triple

Tags: sparql, rdf, dbpedia

I'm trying to list all properties in DBpedia and how many times a property appears in a triple. So I tried this and it doesn't give me all DBpedia properties.

```
SELECT ?prop, (COUNT(?prop) AS ?c)

WHERE {
 ?s ?prop ?o.
}

GROUP BY ?prop  
ORDER BY DESC(?c)
```

Comment: the query is correct so how did you verify that is doesn't return all properties?

Comment: By the way,  speaking of the public DBpedia endpoint which is a shared service, thus, needs some fairness settings, you're aware of i) the limit of returned results and ii) the Virtuoso anytime feature?

Comment: I only got 31 rows that why i said it doesn't return all properties.

Comment: Ok, then see my second comment. There are limitations on the DBpedia endpoint to ensure fair use.

Comment: Please see [this article to learn about the limitations on the public endpoint](https://medium.com/virtuoso-blog/8cae1b81ca71). Depending on your goals, options include [spinning up your own DBpedia mirror in the AWS Cloud](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B07BQKYGYQ).